# String comparison issue in bash script

Tags: string, bash

I wrote the bellow script the purpose of the script is to find all files that start with foo and are no older  3 days sort them then compare them against the list of files in the list file. And to repot only files that are missing. The problem with my script is that it doesn’t not take in to account a missing file ie see below example
Let’s say my file called list contains foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5 but in the event that one file files is missing the string comparison is off.  Ie if file foo4 is missing when the script is ran foo5 would be compared foo4

Hope that makes sense

```
enter  

#!/bin/bash
Set –x
Find ~/test99 –name “foo*” –mtime -3 –print>report
Sort report –o report;
Cat report|cut -c 22-25>report1;
while read comp1<&3 && read comp2<&4
do
    if [[ $comp1 = $comp2 ]]; then
    echo "file not found" >/dev/null
else
    echo "$comp1 not found"
fi
done 3<report1 4<list
```

Comment: You forgot the dollar sign before the `comp2` variable in the comparison. It should be `if [[ $comp1 == "$comp2" ]]; then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to use `diff` for comparing the lists

or you can use `fgrep -vf report list` to get the difference between list and report

Comment: How do you suggest I use diff as I am testing to see if a list of files exists by having it take input from the file called “list” then using find to search for a list of files and output the results to file called reports and compare the output to the list file.

Comment: it would greatly aid giving a better answer if you could clarify the question more clearly....i think you want to get the difference between `list` and `report`

Comment: Ok I understand what you are saying now. I am using fgrep –vf to get the difference which is working. But I only want it to echo what file is missing.  My code now looks like the below. The test is working as it should be but my logic is wrong. I would it to only echo when a file is missing 
`Fgrep –vf report1 output`
`If [[ -s $output ]] then` 
`Echo no file missing`
`else `
`Echo “a file is missing”` 
`fi`

Comment: The file “output” file always tests true regardless if it exists and contains a size grater then 0.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.